# Dynamic generate GridView - Pivot or return anonymous Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pivot-table, anonymous-types

I need some help, 
I'm using a gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridMatrizes" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AllowPaging="true"
    OnRowDataBound="gridMatrizes_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gridMatrizes_RowCommand" OnPageIndexChanging="gridMatrizes_PageIndexChanging"
    PageSize="20" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover ">
    <Columns>
    </Columns>
    <PagerSettings Mode="Numeric" PageButtonCount="20" Position="Bottom" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="center" VerticalAlign="Bottom" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:GridView>
```

and generating columns in codebehind:

```
qsBll qsBll = new qsBll();
BaseRequest<Model.Propriedades> request_propriedades = new BaseRequest<Model.Propriedades> { };

var response = qsBll.Select_Propriedade(request_propriedades).Items;

foreach (var item in response)
{
    BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
    bfield.HeaderText = item.Propriedade;
    bfield.DataField = item.Propriedade;
    gridMatrizes.Columns.Add(bfield);
}
```

so i need to take all the values form my database and put in the associated header...
for example im my database i have something like this:

`Matriz_id  Propriedade Valor_id
    1   Codigo  1

    1   Sabor   4`
I need to put "Codigo" in header and the value 1 in the databound field.

If my Matriz_id has 9 values in database, my gridview will have 9 columns, if it has 2 it will have 2 columns, and so on...
I tryed as a pivot or create a List, but i'm failing...

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like

```
    gridMatrizes.DataSource = response;
    gridMatrizes.DataBind();
```

That should do your column headers automatically as you set AutoGenerateColumns to true

Edit:

So if you want to take apart column and use them headers sometimes, data other times, I'd use a custom holder class;

```
    public class RepsonseHolder()
    {

         public string Valor {get;set;}
         public string Codigo {get;set;}
    }



    var myList = new List<RepsonseHolder>();

    foreach (var item in response)
    {
         var newHolder = new RepsonseHolder();
         newHolder.Valor = item.Column(5);  // Or however you can get at your Ids
         newHolder.Cordigo = item.Column(7);
         myList.Add(newHolder);
    }
```

If you can't get at columns in your Item, you'll have to string split, or use fixed width or something.

Then

```
    gridMatrizes.DataSource = myList;
    gridMatrizes.DataBind();
```

Anyway, the header will be the name of the property you declare, so it can't have spaces in it. If you want spaces you'll need to manually change the Headers, which is messy

Right, Final Update;
This will only work if there's an even number of columns, once the data section starts.

```
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.Append("<table>");
     int columnCounter;
      sb.Append("<tr>");
     var firstRow = response[0]; // Use the first row to get the headers
    for(int i = 2; i < firstRow.Columns; i = i + 2)  //Start at your first HeaderDataPair
    {
         sb.Append("<td>" + firstRow.Column[i] + "</td>");
          columnCounter++;
   }
   sb.Append("</tr>");

    foreach (var item in response)
    {
         sb.Append("<tr>");
         for(int i = 3; i < columnCounter; i = i + 2) //Start one after the first Pair
         {
               sb.Append("<td>" +item.Column[i] + "</td>");
          }
          sb.Append("</tr>");
    }
     sb.Append("</table>");
```

Then databind the sb.ToString();
Note, this is just a rough idea. Coded really roughly, don't try to copy and paste it.

Comment: i need bind the column "Propriedade" as the gridview's Column header and the Valor_id as the value of this column...

Comment: We are getting closer, but 1 of my problems is i dont know how many columns my grid will have, for example:
Matriz_id Propriedade Valor
1 Código 10
1 Tipo 1
1 Classe 3
1 Cor 4
1 Teor 4
2 Estilo 3
2 Bebida de Origem 3
2 Sabor 5
2 teste 1
2   Código 1
2 Cor 4

i need to show in my grid all the "propriedades" with related value of "valor" for example:
Código Tipo Classe Cor Teor
10     1 3  4 4

so i cannot create a class with all "propriedades" values couse they are variables

Comment: Damn, you need to have a word with whoever is sending you this data...it's crappy stuff to work with, I'll update my answer one more time

Comment: Right, I'm off, I'm sure there's a much more elegant way to do this, but I gotta head off for the evening.

Comment: Thank you man, im trying to do this, if i get success i will inform.